# Clarification Needed: Using Rsync to Move /usr

Tags: systemd, partition, rsync, gentoo, ssd

### Context

I recently migrated Windows 10 and Gentoo to 2 separate 250 GB SSD's and left my old traditional SATA HDD Drives in to use for Storage.

1. I put `Users` on a HDD for Windows during a new install.
2. I used a GParted LiveCD to shrink my root file system, and copied it to the new drive, rebooted, and then deleted the old root  I'm leaving `/home` and a swap partition on my HDD Drive.  This all works great, as I'm booting using the UUID's.

Since I'm on Gentoo, I need to move just the `/usr` directory from the SSD back to the original HDD I copied it from, so that the Portage Tree doesn't hog the small SSD space during updates.  I'm not tagging this with gentoo until now(See Update Heading), because this question is related to the proper command options needed for `rsync` For a bit of context, the portage tree is Gentoo's package repository.  The entire repository is downloaded to the user's local machine before updating. Downloading it to the SSD would cause needless wear, as the tree is updated daily.

### Issue

I found the following two questions related to what I'm trying to accomplish:

1. [ServerFault: Mount /usr on different partition](https://serverfault.com/questions/597779/mount-usr-on-different-partition)
2. [AskUbuntu: How to move /usr to a new partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/656/how-to-move-usr-to-a-new-partition)

Now I need an answer to a few of my own questions:

1. Can I use the `rsync` command to move `/usr` while in the Gentoo install where `/usr` needs to be moved?  The ServerFault question hints at this.
2. If #1 isn't possible, and I use the GParted Live USB to issue the `rsync` command, do the file/directory owners change since the LiveUSB is based on a Debian distribution?
3. What are the proper options for `rsync` besides `-a` for archive?  The comments in the selected answer at AskUbuntu hint at adding `-H` to ensure hardlinks are followed, but then the OP contradicts the comments in his own answer.

### Visual Aids

I need to move the `/usr` directory from the partition squared in red to the empty partition squared in blue, while the entire partition squared in red is running, or use a LiveCD to do so, without harming or changing the current permissions.

[image: /usr is in this partition]
[image: Empty Partition]

### Update

This question turned out to be a mountain that can be conquered, but I don't know if I conquer it:

1. I am/was able to move `/usr` to a new partition using `rsync -avAHPX /mnt/gentoo/usr /mnt/new_usr`. I can't give credit for a partial answer as I'm still stuck.
2. It does no good, as systemd complains that the root filesystem doesn't contain a valid init because the init system is in the partition that can't be mounted.  Do you see the issue here? (Systemd is located in `/usr/lib/systemd`)
3. I need [early userspace mounting](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Early_Userspace_Mounting) in order to fix the issue, but in order to do that, I'd lose my Plymouth boot screen initramfs with the initramfs it takes to mount `/usr` early. See also [Custom Initramfs](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Custom_Initramfs) and [Initramfs/Guide](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Initramfs/Guide).
4. Support and or other Gentoo users not complaining that "Systemd Sucks" are hard to come by (which is one of the reasons, I started contributing here).  As such, if I post a question in our official resources, I get booed.

---

If anyone can tell me the proper tools to use that combine both a plymouth bootsplash and early `/usr` mounting in the initramfs/intramfd, I'd appreciate it, and I'm thinking about offering a bounty, if this question sits.  Also know that since Gentoo is source based that even though I linked the Gentoo Wiki articles, that I can use the tools from other distributions.

Comment: I don't exactly understand the first part. Are you asking if you should copy `/usr` into a running system? If so, then no, much safer to use a live USB. I presume GParted has rsync, but if you are worried, then just use the Gentoo live USB instead. I'd use `-aP` at a minimum. I'm not sure if there'd be any hardlinks on `/usr`, but no harm doing `-H` if there isn't. (By the same token, you could use `-AX` too.)

Comment: Was working on answering another question when your comment came up.  I know I can issue a `man rsync` to read the options you posted, but do you mind explaining the reasons I should add  `-X` or `-P`? And to clarify, I need to copy the /usr folder from a running system into some free space.  I'll post a screen capture of GParted.

Comment: @Sparhawk I added screenshots if that helps.

Comment: Copying `/usr` on a live system shouldn't be a problem, `/usr` is (or was, originally) designed to be able to be mounted read-only, and shared between multiple systems, as its contents should only change when upgrades are done. `-P` is shorthand for `--partial --progress` which doesn't affect the final result of the rsync transffer. `-X` preserves extended attributes if you use those.

Comment: Simple can suggest `rsync -a --progress /usr/ /path/to/usr/` (don't forget trailing slashes otherwise you could end with folder being copied to /path/to/usr/usr

Comment: @AntonyGibbs I've already moved it.  See Update.  The issue here is: Update Bullet 2

Comment: ok sorry... guessing you are using a simlink similar to this `ln -s /mnt/hdc1/usr /usr` ?  have you tried adding a line in /etc/fstab so that /mnt/hdc1 is mounted at boot? (assuming you have rsynced to hdc1)

Comment: @AntonyGibbs yes, I use UUIDS to easily mount partitions.  Symlinking doesn't work here as `/usr` doesnt mount before `/`

Comment: did you give it the option `defaults` in fstab?

Comment: Of course.  Please read the early userspace mounting link, as the initramfs doesn't read from the fstab anyway

Comment: in your gentoo_usr you only have the content of /usr ?
if so, in fstab you mount it directly as `/usr` (and no symlink is needed)

Comment: mount only works on a empty folder so in your root partition /usr has to be an empty folder

Comment: it's easy done to end with something like `/usr/usr` ... always good to check

Comment: and if you want to save writing to your SSD (and that you have a bit of ram) this in fstab can help `tmpfs           /tmp tmpfs defaults,size=8g,nr_inodes=0 0 0`

and specially playing around with mysql you would want the same line pointing to /var/tmp

Comment: Can you post the init script you're using for your custom initramfs? Also, the output of `zcat /boot/initramfs-linux.img | cpio -iv --to-stdout init` would be helpful, assuming `/boot/initramfs-linux.img` is the path to your default initramfs (the one with plymouth).

Comment: @LayneBernardo I used genkernel-next to generate the initramfs. Do you still want the output

Comment: It looks like genkernel-next has options to enable plymouth. This guide explains: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Plymouth#Genkernel-Next You should be able to generate a custom initramfs that mounts /usr early and still has plymouth

Comment: Exactly, but how?  The early userspace wiki entry is manual, genkernel-next and Plymouth are automatic, and grub only allows one initramfs. Now you see why I’ve posted a bounty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I suggest an alternative method?

- Don't try to move entire `/usr/*` tree since you mentioned it broke systemd and also doesn't seem to be required to resolve your issues of intensive RW and/or large amount of wasted space (you can just move `/usr/portage`)
- Copy `/usr/portage` to a remote HDD via rsync running from LiveCD
- Mount HDD at startup via FSTAB to somewhere like `/mnt/hdd`
- Recursively delete `/usr/portage`
- Symlink `ln -s /mnt/hdd/gentoo/usr/portage /usr/portage`

I prefer not to modify default directories (`/usr/portage` is default, but I believe you can modify that) unless needed and if I want them to reside on another HDD I will just symlink them. You could just make another partition for just `/usr/portage` and mount it directly to `/usr/portage`, but I prefer to do something like mount all my data in one big remote partition under `/mnt/data` and then symlink directories as needed. I would likely have `/home` reside here as well.

Perhaps two separate partition scheme like so :

```
/mnt/os_data
/mnt/my_data
```

I figure you get the gist.

Comment: this is a lot of work to save on SSD space, for my "OS's" I generally only need ~150GB for Windows and I like to have say ~30GB for Linux. I then store all personal data on a separate HDD. I would be only concerned with the intensive RW you mentioned.

Comment: I thought this would be an easier process than it turned out to be. I’ll consider this method, but I’ll wait the full 7 days in case others answer with creating the Initial Ramdisk etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. Can I use the `rsync` command to move `/usr` while in the Gentoo install where `/usr` needs to be moved?  The ServerFault question hints at this.

Yes, you certainly can (copy, not move?), but I would always use a Live USB for these kinds of things. On a system in use, it's plausible that some process writes to `/usr` while you are copying it, which could potentially result in an incomplete transfer.

2. If #1 isn't possible, and I use the GParted Live USB to issue the `rsync` command, do the file/directory owners change since the LiveUSB is based on a Debian distribution?

No, as long as you are using `-a`, permissions should be preserved for a local copy.

3. What are the proper options for `rsync` besides `-a` for archive?  The comments in the selected answer at AskUbuntu hint at adding `-H` to ensure hardlinks are followed, but then the OP contradicts the comments in his own answer.

As discussed in the comments, if you look for `-a` in `man rsync`, it excludes `-H`, `-A`, and `-X`. These flags preserve hard links, ACLs, and extended attributes. I strongly doubt that `/usr` contains any of these, but there is no harm in using the flags, just in case. If the source doesn't use them, then there is nothing to preserve, so `rsync` would function just as if you had not used the flags. I also tend to use `-P`, which allows you to continue aborted transfers, and also shows you the progress as you are copying.